# getting custom CSS class when using emmet in html files

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, emmet

I would like to get autocomplete suggestions of my custom css class when I'm using emmet in HTML files

so when I type `div.[suggestions with my CSS classes]` like when the suggestions I get when inside of class attribute `<div class=" ">`

like in here but when using emmet

[image: like in here but when using emmet]

Comment: those suggestions are probably from some kind of extension, it is not standard VSC behavior.

Comment: I figured out that they come from 2 extentions that I have. 
1- `HTML CSS Support`
2-  `IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML`
Sadly they doesn't appear in emmet abbreviation, but I found some workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a quriky solution to it, but not as elegent

1. Download [IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion)
2. open vscode go to settings by `ctrl + ,`
3. go the JSON file from top right corner [image: file with return arrow]
4. add that line `"html-css-class-completion.enableEmmetSupport": true,`

It will be used in the following order

1. typing a tag (e.g `div`) followed by `.`
2. choosing the class [image: suggested classes]
3. pressing `ctrl + space` again to get emmet abbreviation option
4. choosing the emmet snippet

voila!